# unicode error displayed on the server on running app (django)

Tags: python, django, linux, unicode, ubuntu-10.04

my views.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
from search.models import Keywords
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
        str1 = request.POST['word'] 
        fo = open("/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt","r")

        for i in range(count.__len__()):

            file = fo.readline()
            file = file.rstrip('\n')
            find_root_tags(file,str1,i) 

            list.append((file,count[i]))

        sorting_list(list)

        for name, count1 in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count1)
            s.save()

        fo.close()

        list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
        t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
        c = RequestContext({'list1':list1,
        })

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

    else :  
        str1 = ''
        list = []
        template = loader.get_template('search/front_page.html')
        c = RequestContext(request)
        response = template.render(c)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

skey.py has another function called within from find_root_tags():

```
        def find_text(file,str1,i):

            str1 = str1.lower()
            exp = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
            with open(file) as f:
            lines = ''.join(line for line in f.readlines())
            text_only = exp.sub('',lines).strip()

            text_only = text_only.lower()
            k = text_only.count(str1)  #**line 34**
            count[i] = count[i]+k
```

when I ran my app on server it gave me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /search/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /home/pooja/Desktop/mysite/search/skey.py in find_text, line 34
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.5
Python Path:     ['/home/pooja/Desktop/mysite',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
                     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
                     '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
                     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0',
                     '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages'] error :
```

Can anyone tell me why is it showing this error?How can I remove this error

Please help.

Comment: can anyone provide me the code .......... please help, it's urgent I don't have time that i can read something

Comment: Please, specify where is *find_text* called?

Comment: See my version of the *find_text*

Comment: I changed my answer. Please test it.

Comment: as a quick hack you could `text_only = text_only.decode(character_encoding)`, but it just shifts the problem elsewhere. The correct fix is to use Unicode strings everywhere internally.

Answer (score 0):

Probable your *str1* is in unicode, but text_only is not (on line 34). The next is not a panacea but if this corrects your problem then I am right.

```
k = u"{0}".format( text_only ).count(str1)
```

Comment: UTF-16 reference is misleading. Unicode strings are sequences of Unicode codepoints (neglecting surrogate pairs). Internal representation of Unicode strings in Python depends on compiler options, python version

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Is my recommendation wrong, about string literals?

Comment: you need to specify a character encoding. Otherwise the same error  happens

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are right if str1 is not a unicode object (UTF-16)

Comment: no, try: `unicode('байты').count(u'unistr')`. It should produce the error

Comment: if text_only is a bytestring you need to specify its character encoding. There is no way around it. Implicit conversion using ASCII encoding will fail sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing Unicode strings and bytestrings. `str1 = request.POST['word']` is probably a Unicode string and `text_only` is a bytestring.  Python fails to convert the later to Unicode. You could use `codecs.open()` to specify the character encoding of the file. See [Pragmatic Unicode](http://bit.ly/unipain) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).